# Problem in Insert Row to mysql remote Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, insert

Good Morning I'm trying to insert a new record in a remote mysql database using PDO.
The code is pretty simple, but the behaviour of the script look very strange.

This is the code:

````
```
<?php
class InsertDataDemo{
const DB_HOST = $host;
const DB_NAME = $db_name;
const DB_USER = $user;
const DB_PASSWORD = $pass;

private $conn = null;

/**
 * Open the database connection
 */
public function __construct(){
    // open database connection
    $connectionString = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s",
            InsertDataDemo::DB_HOST,
            InsertDataDemo::DB_NAME);
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO($connectionString,
                InsertDataDemo::DB_USER,
                InsertDataDemo::DB_PASSWORD);

    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die($pe->getMessage());
    }
}



/**
* insert a new task into the tasks table
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $description
 * @param string $startDate
 * @param string $endDate
 * @return mixed returns false on failure 
 */
 
 
function insertSingleRow($id_anagrafica, $cognome, $nome, $sesso, $dt_nascita, $lg_nascita, $cd_fiscale, $indirizzo, $lg_residenza, $cap, $tel_cellulare, $email, $origine, $note_anag, $medico_cur, $dt_cancel) {
    $task = array(':id_anagrafica' => $id_anagrafica,
                  ':cognome' => $cognome,
                  ':nome' => $nome,
                  ':sesso' => $sesso,
                  ':dt_nascita' => $dt_nascita,
                  ':lg_nascita' => $lg_nascita,
                  ':cd_fiscale' => $cd_fiscale,
                  ':indirizzo' => $indirizzo,
                  ':lg_residenza' => $lg_residenza,
                  ':cap' => $cap,
                  ':tel_cellulare' => $tel_cellulare,
                  ':email' => $email,
                  ':origine' => $origine,
                  ':note_anag' => $note_anag,
                  ':medico_cur' => $medico_cur,
                  ':dt_cancel' => $dt_cancel,
                  );

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO t_anagra_ext(id_anagrafica, cognome, nome, sesso, dt_nascita, lg_nascita, cd_fiscale, indirizzo, lg_residenza, cap, tel_cellulare, email, origine, note_anag, medico_cur, dt_cancel)
            VALUES(:id_anagrafica,:cognome,:nome,:sesso,:dt_nascita,:lg_nascita,:cd_fiscale,:indirizzo,:lg_residenza,:cap,:tel_cellulare,:email,:origine,:note_anag,:medico_cur,:dt_cancel)';

    $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    return $q->execute($task);
}

function readRows(){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM t_anagra_ext ORDER BY id_anagrafica ASC';
    foreach ($this->conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['id_anagrafica'] . "\t";
        print $row['cognome'] . "\t";
        print $row['nome'] . "</br>";
    }
    

}


/**
 * close the database connection
 */
public function __destruct() {
    // close the database connection
    $this->conn = null;
}
}

$obj = new InsertDataDemo();


echo "Read Rows before insert"."</br></br>";
$obj->ReadRows();
echo "</br></br>";

echo "Do insert"."</br></br>";
if($obj->insertSingleRow('7270','Maignan','Mike','F','2022-03- 
                          02','A001','ZLMRJQ33R52I752N','via san lorenzo 
             18','A001','00100','3283653934','alekseys85@gmail.com','ciao','ciao','ciao',NULL) 
    !== false)

echo 'A new task has been added successfully'."</br></br>";
else 
echo 'Error adding the task'."</br></br>";

echo "Read Rows after insert"."</br></br>";
$obj->ReadRows();

```
````

When I execute the code I See:

Read Rows before insert

```
823 Albano Salvatore
109201 SIMONE MILETTA
109202 PROVA grant
109203 PROVA due
```

Do insert

A new task has been added successfully

Read Rows after insert

```
823 Albano Salvatore
7270 Maignan Mike
109201 SIMONE MILETTA
109202 PROVA grant
109203 PROVA due
```

but nothing changes in DB

where I'm going wrong?

If I execute the query in mysql workbench it works.
thank you

Comment: Are you looking in the correct database? Or: Are you inserting in the correct database? In other words: It seems like you're running your PHP script on one database, and then check for changes in another database. Otherwise I cannot explain it, unless you're checking very poorly. The script clearly shows that the database has changed.

Comment: the database is correct, because I've no other db with that table. The database looks changed but if i change the query and run it again, records in the table are always the same ( the four you can see)

Comment: Try to be exact in what you write: 1. _"if i change the query"_ there are 2 queries, which one did you change? And why? 2. _"records in the table are always the same"_, but I can see the records change when you run the script.

Comment: I mean if I change the insert values with others the scenario is the same: pre-insert read shows same 4 records:

823 Albano Salvatore
109201 SIMONE MILETTA
109202 PROVA grant
109203 PROVA due